# Laravel and jwt token . JWTException for unknown reason

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, token, tymon-jwt

I am building a medication warehouse management system. I had encountered the need to use JWT token to apply authentication.

My model of the object that should be authenticated:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class Pharmacist extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use HasFactory;
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
    
    protected $table = 'pharmacists';
    protected $fillable = ['name_ar', 'name_en', 'phone_number', 'password', 'pharmacy_name_ar', 'pharmacy_name_en', 'status', 'email', 'location_id'];


    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Token generating method:

```
$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($pharmacist, ['isAdmin' => false]);
```

Where `$pharmacist` is an object of the Pharmacist Model.

And the middleware is as follows:

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;

class isAuth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {

        try {
            $token = $request->header('Authorization');
            $token = str_replace('Bearer ', '', $token);

            $user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);

            $payload = JWTAuth::getPayload($token)->toArray();
            $isAdmin = $payload['isAdmin'] ?? null;

            if ($isAdmin) {
                $request->merge(['admin' => $user]);
            } else {
                $request->merge(['pharmacist' => $user]);
            }

            return $next($request);
        } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Token expired'], 401);
        } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Token invalid'], 401);
        } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Token absent'], 401);
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is, it is always returning with the response of "Token absent" which means it is a JWTException. Although the value of the `$token` var is correct. What could the problem be?

Please note that I have deleted the User model that is generated automatically when creating a Laravel project. Does that have anything to do with my problem?

The excpetion is thrown from the `$token->toUser()` method.

The log of the exception is as follows :

> Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException: A token is required in
> C:\X\BackEnd\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\JWT.php:318
>
> vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\JWT.php(192):
> Tymon\JWTAuth\JWT->requireToken().
>
> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(353):
> Tymon\JWTAuth\JWT->getPayload('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV 1Q...').

And continues to :

> BackEnd\public\index.php(51):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

Comment: Can you point out which line is throwing the exception from the code that you have shared?

Comment: What's the result of `$request->header('Authorization')` ?